# Stopping for loop until method calls onFinished()

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, countdowntimer

How can I stop the for loop and wait until the method has finished and continue once it has called `onFinish()`?

One solution I could think of was using `listeners` and calling that when the method calls `onFinish()`, but I do not know how to stop the loop and wait for the `listener`. Also functions like `wait()` would not work because the `doCountDown()` could take more or less than the `wait()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    doCountDown();
    //Pause and wait for doCountDown() to finish
}

private void doCountDown(){

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CountDownTimer(30000,100) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //Do some stuff
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        //Continue loop
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: As somebody mentioned, `wait` and `notify` are the java methods for waking sleeping threads, but in this case, since the calculation is synchronous and serial, why do you not implement the entire loop inside a single thread? Why do you need to create a new thread each time the loop repeats?

Comment: Because i need the timer and the interval for each iteration

Comment: aha, now I got it. Then you can start only 1 `Countdown` timer and increase the start time instead of creating several timers one by one with smaller amount of ticks in a loop. If it's really neccessary to instantiate several timers, then I would use the solution either of @Richard or @aka-one, but handle deadlock by setting timeout on wait for the case anything would go wrong.

Comment: @fairtrax how would you do the "Then you can start only 1 ..." Because when doing the `Richard` solution the program falls behind on timers since creating a new handler takes a little time itself

Comment: I wrote an answer with my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use recursion which would get you the result you need.

```
doAnotherLine(0);

private void doAnotherLine(int i){
    //Some stopper method.. for example something like this
    if(i < list.size -1) doCountDown(i);

}

private void doCountDown(final int i){

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CountDownTimer(30000,100) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //Do some stuff
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        doAnotherLine(i+1);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Well that actually works but how safe is it to do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). It is reusable, so you dont have create it each time.

```
// this will create barrier for 2 parties.
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    doCountDown();
    //Pause and wait for doCountDown() to finish
    // add try catch around for interrup exception
       barrier.await();
}
.......
@Override
public void onFinish() {
     ////Continue loop
      barrier.await();
}
```

Comment: How good is this performance wise and in comparison to `wait()/notify`.

Comment: wait/notfify should have perform better. but I dont know for sure

Comment: For some reason neither this or the answer above works.

Comment: if your code reaches the onFinish method this should work.

Comment: Without barrier or the syncronized.. it reaches there.. if i add them it does not reach it anymore.

Comment: Is it possible that `wait()` or `await` also stops the handler from running the `CountDownTimer` ?

Comment: I don't know.. it doest work at all with wait/notify and if i switch the parties variable to 1 then it does all the loops together ignoring the stops, but when i switch the parties variable to 2, then everything stops and nothing works.

And debugging gives no results either.

Comment: @kataroty Looks like your for loop is running on ui threat. (It is bad practice to wait on ui threat, it will cause your ui to freeze) Looper.getMainLooper()) code also executes on ui threat. Just use new Runnable(). start() on doCountDown method. But at the end you will freeze the ui for the duration of this method.(You should change your design)

Comment: @kataroty Are you sure you do call wait and notify on **the same object**? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

It's working with `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` methods.

```
// Whatever object
Object obj = new Object();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            doCountDown(obj);
            // Pause and wait for doCountDown() to finish
            synchronized (obj) {
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    private void doCountDown(Object obj) {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CountDownTimer(30000, 100) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // Do some stuff
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // Continue loop
                        synchronized (obj) {
                            obj.notify();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

here the answer to your comment about implementing only 1 timer at all:

```
private void doCountDowns(int count){

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int timer = 0; // if each timer does something else
            int ticks = 0;
            new CountDownTimer(30000 * count,100) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //Do some stuff
                    if ((ticks++) == 3000) {
                        ticks = 0;
                        timer++;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // called only once, when everything is done
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

`doCountDowns(10)` would start a timer for 10x 30000ms, that ticks 3000x (every 100ms). May it solve your problem? If each of your timer has another task (however it doesn't seem to be that case), you can introduce `ticks` and `timer` fields to count the ticks count and timer.

Maybe you could try to explain, why you need 10 timers each to be ticking for 30.000 ms and not 1 timer ticking for 300.000 ms.

Comment: I need each timer to tick for 30 000ms (well the time changes depending on the gap), because I am trying to draw the lyrics one line at a time. The 30 000 or whatever number comes from the `.lrc` file where I get the difference between 2 times (which gives me the time gap in which time i need to finish coloring the full line of lyrics). So I am guessing it does not solve my problem. Unless I start the timer for the full song duration and then capture each line with a different `if`. But nevertheless, I thank you for your answer.